# error 156 severity 15 state 1 using syntax CASE WHEN ELSE END

Tags: sql, sql-server, switch-statement

I have new WHERE condition when @Keyword is declare from Store Procedure. but when I tried CASE syntax, I have error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword ‘LIKE’."

I have tried this CASE syntax in PostgreSQL but no error.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ACC_SEARCH_INVOICE_DATEX]
@projectID  varchar(3),
@FromDate DATETIME,
@Todate DATETIME ,
@Filter varchar(50),
@Keyword varchar(50),
@posted int,

@status integer,
@source varchar(50)
AS

SELECT posted, InvoiceHead.InvoiceID, InvoiceHead.Date AS date, InvoiceHead.UserID, InvoiceHead.CreditTerm, InvoiceHead.DueDate, InvoiceHead.CustomerID, 
Party.Name, InvoiceHead.Total, InvoiceHead.Currency, InvoiceHead.Rate, Subtotal, Discount, Tax, Commision, Bonus, Total, DownPayment, Balance ,
substring(InvoiceID,4,LEN(invoiceid)-11-3) Source, selling, technician, Lock , InvoiceHead.Status

FROM InvoiceHead LEFT OUTER JOIN Party ON InvoiceHead.CustomerID = Party.PartyID  

WHERE 

CASE
 WHEN @Keyword = 'SCP' 
    THEN ((InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%') or (InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%SCJ%'))
 WHEN  @Keyword = 'SCNH' 
    THEN ((InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%') or (InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%SNJH%'))
 WHEN  @Keyword = 'SCNHL' 
    THEN ((InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%') or (InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%SNJHL%'))
 ELSE ((InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%'))
END

ORDER BY   InvoiceHead.InvoiceID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can frame this logic without the `case`.  I would recommend the following:

```
WHERE InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%') OR
      (@Keyword = 'SCP' AND InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%SCJ%') OR
      (@Keyword = 'SCNH' AND InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%SNJH%') OR
      (@Keyword = 'SCNHL' AND InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%SNJHL%');
```

SQL Server doesn't have a boolean type.  You are getting an error because your `CASE` expression is returning boolean expressions, but that is not a valid value in SQL Server.

In general, it is considered simpler to use boolean operators for `WHERE` conditions rather than introducing `CASE`.

Answer (score 0):

You should reframe condition:

```
WHERE 
(CASE
 WHEN @Keyword = 'SCP'   AND ((InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%') or (InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%SCJ%'))   THEN 1
 WHEN @Keyword = 'SCNH'  AND ((InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%') or (InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%SNJH%'))  THEN 1
 WHEN @Keyword = 'SCNHL' AND ((InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%') or (InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%SNJHL%')) THEN 1
 WHEN ((InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%')) THEN 1
END) = 1
```

Comment: While that would work, it should really be rewritten as `where (..) or (..) or (..)`.

Comment: @GSerg Yes, that was another possibility. I just wanted to point out that CASE expression after THEN should return value not another condition.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like below

```
WHERE (@Keyword = 'SCP'   AND ((InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%') or (InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%SCJ%'))) 
  OR  (@Keyword = 'SCNH' AND ((InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%') or (InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%SNJH%')))
  OR  (@Keyword = 'SCNHL' AND ((InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%') or (InvoiceHead.InvoiceID LIKE '%SNJHL%')))
```